Access database not closing properly
I have Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2021 on my laptop.
I am the admin and the only person that uses it. 
Access has begun acting strangely. 
When I exit out of the application, it closes the window but does not completely close Access. 
I tracked it down to this code in the form_load of my main form
strPropValue = CurrentDb.Containers("Databases"("UserDefined").Properties(strPropRevision)

I have tried changing the client settings
When I tried
File -> options -> client settings -> Advanced -> Default Open Mode = Exclusive
when I close Access I get the message

  Could not use ; file already in use

the Task Manager background process has Microsoft Access
the database won't open - need to end task in task manager
When I tried
File -> options -> client settings -> Advanced -> Default Open Mode = Shared
when I close Access i get the message

You attempted to open database that is already opened by user 'admin' on machine
'LAPTOP-HP', Try again when the database is available.

the .laccdb file is not deleted
the Task Manager background process has Microsoft Access
I have read about application.quit and docmd.quit but it didn't make a difference.
This code has been working and just stopped.  Maybe it is because of a recent update but I don't know where I would look.
I moved the .accdb file to a different folder but it made no difference.

I am not familiar with that code. What is its purpose? As posted, it is missing a closing parenthesis. Does code compile?

Could this be related to the recent update  or this issue from a few months ago?

"I tracked it down to this code in the form_load of my main form" I've also never seen such a code ... what is that? What does it do? What is it for? Any more context or details on this?

It returns the value associated with a property in the container.  The extra paren at the beginning is a typo.  The code compiles and works.

It might be related to that issue @DecimalTurn it certainly sounds like it.  Adding the path to trusted locations worked

In Trust Center, add your Access file location containing the VBA code to trusted locations. I hope this helps.
